# Как сократить ссылку на площадке S3 Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Всем привет. Использую S3 Amazon как хостинг, проблема в том, что не могу сократить ссылку.

1. Амазаон даёт такую ссылку bucket.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/my/site
2. Мне нужена ссылка, без слова "Bucket" s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/my/site
   Что нужно сделать ?

Comment: [Shorten S3 signed url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37112290/312041)

Comment: Читал об этом, но не понял, что добавлять в метадату

Comment: Попробую еще раз описать. Изначально выглядит так - mybucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/file/index.html Мне нужно так - s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/file/index.html Когда стираю слово "mybucket", сайт не открывается. Что нужно сделать ?

Comment: Нужно включить в настройках бакета static website hosting, см документацию s3 по этому запросу.